# Unexplained delay in WCF Trace

Tags: performance, wcf, trace

[image: Trace Screenshot]

I'm having intermittent issues with WCF calls taking minutes where before they used to be sub-second.

I'm using the xxAsync methods and a new proxy with each call. Binding is Http and up till our latest code release this worked fine. We've reviewed the release and can't see anything that would directly explain the issue.

In the screen shot I have highlighted the key entries. Between these two lines we lose 2 minutes.

My question is - what is happening between/inside these two events that might lead me to the issue?

Comment: Try to enable `System.ServiceModel` trace source with `Verbose` level. If this is not enough, then add `System.Runtime.Serialization` trace source also with `Verbose` level. This should give you good hint of what's happening inside WCF.

Comment: Thanks @IgorLabutin - I'll set that running and see what happens